# Link to section of another page working...but then again, it isn't

Tags: hyperlink, anchor

So, I have this strange issue! And it's driving me batty! lol

I'm trying to link to a section of another page using:

`<a href="about.php#team">Our Team</a>`

On the about page, I have:

`<p id="team">`

I tried it with `<div id="team">`, `<div id="team" name="team">`, yadda, and I had the same issue.

It works fine! It goes to the about.php page, and to the 'team' section! But then, it goes straight back to the top of the page! Ugh!

I am running Bootstrap v3.2.0 (haven't upgraded yet), and the top of the page has scrolling images, so I don't know if that could be the reason? Or if it's something else.

Here is the link to the page in question:

[about.php](https://piccs.info/about.php)

And to the main page where I'm linking from:

[index.php](https://piccs.info)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!!